# Detecting user activity in Windows without polling

Tags: windows

I'm aware there is an idle timer and event in Windows that we can hook onto.
Is there an event for the opposite of this?
i.e. i.e. an event that fires when there is activity on one of the HID devices?

I'm aware of `GetLastInputState`, but that is polling.
Global hooking is also an overkill.

My interest is in that the monitor switches on when the keyboard/mouse has activity, is there a way to hook into that?

Thank you.

Comment: You can observe input using Raw Input.

Comment: Do you mean global hooking?

Comment: [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) allows an application to receive global input. Unlike (low-level) input hooks this won't allow you to affect the system's input processing. Raw Input is strictly an event sink.